# AngularJS: Ag-grid cellRenderer processing my datetime, and adding an hour to value?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, cellrenderer

When passing my value from my function that returns the current date time, the built in ag-grid cell renderer is adding an hour and displaying this, however the data is being loaded into the backend as the correct value which is being passed in and upon refreshing the page the time is correct.

Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

i.e
      function myDate(date) {
      if(date)
     {
    return $filter(‘date’)(new Date(date), ‘M/d/yyyy h:mm a              est’)
}
    var myGrid = [{
    headerName:header,
    field:headField,
    filter:date,
    cellRenderer: function(row)
    {
        return myDate(row.data.headField);
    {
}

myDate returns 11:00 am est at 11am est but initially displays 12:00pm until refreshing the page.

Comment: Please provide code details in which are you facing an issue. This is too broad to be debugged exactly for your case.

Comment: Code added for reference